# Performance analysis of CPUs for parallel executions

Tags: multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, cpu

Recently, I did a "parallel speedup" comparison between two computers with different specifications

1- Single AMD Ryzen 7 1800x running at 3.6GHz. This cpu has 8 physical cores and 16 logical cores ([here](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-1800x)).

2- Dual Xeon 2695 v3 (Haswell) running at 2.3GHz on one motherboard. Each cpu has 14 physical cores. So, total physical cores are 28 and total logical cores are 56 ([here](https://ark.intel.com/products/81057/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2695-v3-35M-Cache-2-30-GHz-)).

I ran one program with different number of threads on both systems. I know that this may not be a fair comparison since the program also uses about 4GB of memory and I didn't tell about memory specs, but the speedup chart is shown below. Note that for each processor,

```
speedup = (time of one thread on that CPU) / (time of N threads on that CPU)
```

Therefore, for 1 thread, both Ryzen and Xeon are scaled to 1.

[image]

If someone looks at the chart, he may say that the speedup of Xeon is better than Ryzen. For example, with 8 cores, Ryzen has 3.4 speedup while Xeon has 4.69 speedup.

However, if we check the time data, we will see that for 8 threads they have the same execution time. Moreover, Ryzen performs better that Xeon. It is obvious that

```
S_ryzen = 900/263        <        S_xeon = 1188/253
```

[image]

So, looking at only speedup data, sound misguiding. On the other hand, I do expect that 8 thread ryzen should have less execution time than Xeon, e.g. 200 seconds since it has better single core performance.

What can be concluded about the performance comparison of these two processors? I know the xeon provides more cores, but taking 8 cores (which both have), which processor has higher performance?

Comment: How did you measure the thread time? What OS? What does the (apparently not very scalable) program do? Have you tried another program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let S(U, N) denotes the speedup obtained on system U where the baseline program (the numerator in the speedup formula) uses 1 thread and the improved program uses N threads. That is:

S(U, N) = Time<sub>U</sub>(1) / Time<sub>U</sub>(N)

Hence:

S(Xeon, 8) > S(Ryzen, 8)

This implies that:

Time<sub>Xeon</sub>(1) / Time<sub>Xeon</sub>(8) > Time<sub>Ryzen</sub>(1) / Time<sub>Ryzen</sub>(8)

But we cannot conclude anything about how any two execution times are related. We can only say that Xeon has *scaled* better (i.e., the program was able to make more effective use of the additional resources on Xeon than on Ryzen), but that doesn't mean that it has *performed* better in terms of execution time. It's just a mathematically invalid conclusion. For example, we can't conclude that Time<sub>Xeon</sub>(8) > Time<sub>Ryzen</sub>(8).

However, we can observe that:

S(Xeon, 8) > S(Xeon, 4)

That is:

Time<sub>Xeon</sub>(1) / Time<sub>Xeon</sub>(8) > Time<sub>Xeon</sub>(1) / Time<sub>Xeon</sub>(4)

The two Time<sub>Xeon</sub>(1) terms cancel each other and we get:

Time<sub>Xeon</sub>(4) > Time<sub>Xeon</sub>(8)

Now here comes the critical observation. Why were we able to deduce from two given speedups how two execution times are related on the same CPU but on on two different CPUs? Because on the same CPU, the baseline is the same in both speedups, which enabled us to cancel them with each other.

So how can we make the same deduction on two different CPUs? By using a shared baseline or reference system. Typically, some old system is chosen as the baseline. For example, you can choose here Willamette, which is a Pentium 4 processor released in 2000. Of course, you need to choose a system that you can run experiments on to measure the baseline execution time. So the speedup can then be calculated as follows:

S<sub>ref</sub>(U, N) = Time<sub>Willamette</sub>(1) / Time<sub>U</sub>(N)

Essentially, Time<sub>Willamette</sub>(1) becomes the shared term. This formula is much more useful than the previous one. For example, you can easily calculate S(U, N) given only S<sub>ref</sub>(U, N) as follows:

S(U, N) = S<sub>ref</sub>(U, N) / S<sub>ref</sub>(U, 1)

So if S<sub>ref</sub>(Xeon, 8) > S<sub>ref</sub>(Xeon, 4), then it's mathematically valid to deduce that Time<sub>Xeon</sub>(8) < Time<sub>Xeon</sub>(4). Also if S<sub>ref</sub>(Xeon, 8) > S<sub>ref</sub>(Ryzen, 8), then it's mathematically valid to deduce that Time<sub>Xeon</sub>(8) < Time<sub>Ryzen</sub>(8). A given relation between two S<sub>ref</sub>(U, N) speedups on the same or different CPUs contains more information compared to using S(U, N).

The [SPEC CPU benchmark suite](https://www.spec.org/cpu2017/) uses this method to normalize performance metrics. The SPEC CPU 2006 suite [uses a machine from 1997](https://www.spec.org/cpu2006/Docs/readme1st.html#Q23):

> SPEC uses a historical Sun system, the "Ultra Enterprise 2" which was
>   introduced in 1997, as the reference machine. The reference machine
>   uses a 296 MHz UltraSPARC II processor, as did the reference machine
>   for CPU2000. But the reference machines for the two suites are not
>   identical: the CPU2006 reference machine has substantially better
>   caches, and the CPU2000 reference machine could not have held enough
>   memory to run CPU2006.

The SPEC CPU 2017 uses [a more modern machine from 2006](https://www.spec.org/cpu2017/Docs/overview.html#Q18):

> The reference machine is a historical Sun Microsystems server, the Sun
>   Fire V490 with 2100 MHz UltraSPARC-IV+ chips. The UltraSPARC-IV+ was
>   introduced in 2006, and is newer than the chip used in the CPU2000 and
>   CPU2006 reference machines (the 300 MHz 1997 UltraSPARC II).

The normalized numbers can be compared against each other whether they are from the same system or different systems.

So the reference system should be the most modern system that is older (in particular, slower) than all the systems of interest (i.e., those that may be compared against each other).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I just want to know why the reference system should be pretty old for the conclusion. For example, The Xeon Haswell in for 2014 and Ryzen is for 2017 or so. I think that a 2012 machine is a good reference because my two machine are released after 2012. Surely, if someone want to compare 2012 machine with 2014 and 1027, he has to choose a 2010 reference. Am I right? or there is a logic for choosing very old reference?

Comment: BTW, FYI, The program is a molecular simulation program. Since the Xeon machine has 2 CPUs, we see total 56 cores. Thing is that both machine has degradation when using the logical cores. The Ryzen is good when 8 physical cores are used and Xeon is good when 28 physical cores are used. However, the degradation of Ryzen is more than Xeon..........

Comment: ......... The degradation trend is pretty similar for both CPUs. So Xeon is not better scaled in my opinion. Moreover, if you look at the speedup degradation of 56 from 28 (Xeon) and compare it to 16 from 8 (Ryzen) you will see that the Xeon drops much more than Ryzen. The speedup of 56 cores (all Xeon cores) is nearly the same as 16 cores (all Ryzen cores). Do you agree with that?

Comment: @mahmood Well, from a pure math perspective, the reference machine can be whatever you want. However, it's a common practice to choose a reference system that is as modern as possible but older than the all the machines of interest. The rationale behind the "as modern as possible part" is so that reference machine is not much slower than the other machines and the normalized numbers are not too large. The rationale behind the "older" part is so that the normalized numbers are mostly...

Comment: ... either all larger than 1 or all smaller than 1 (depending on whether the performance of the reference machine is used in the numerator or denominator). This makes analyzing the numbers a bit easier and the corresponding graphs would look nicer. This guideline is essentially driven by art, not math. For example, if Haswell and Ryzen are the only two machines that you want to study. Then you can choose one of them as the reference machine. If there are more than two machines, then you can pick the oldest (slowest) one of them as the reference machine.

Comment: The reference machine may not be slower than the other machines in all cases, that's also fine.

Comment: @mahmood Regarding your second comment, I'm not sure if you are referring to the degradation of execution time or speedup. In case of execution time, we can use linear regression to find a line that best fits both curves when the number of threads is larger than 8 on both CPUs. The slope of the line determines salability and the smaller the slope the better the salability. I'm not sure but it does look to me like the slope of the line that fits the Xeon curve is a little smaller than that that firsts Ryzen...

Comment: ...Anyway, I don't think it makes to compare the salability of Xeon for thread count > 16 with Ryzen. This is not a fair comparison. You should use a Ryzen processor with the same number of cores (preferably physical and logical). For example, comparing 56 vs. 28 on  Xeon with 16 vs. 8 on Ryzen is not really fair. When the number of cores get larger, salability gets harder to attain.